# Java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property ‘x’ on null object - when running a groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I run a groovy script through the transport client:
The script looks like this:

```
if (ctx._source.field.names == null) 
   ctx._source.field.names=newItems 
else 
   ctx._source.field.names<< newItems; 
ctx._source.field.names = ctx._source.field.names.flatten().unique()
```

My problem is that most of the times it works but sometimes I get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script 
   at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:256) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1] 
   at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:196) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1] 
   at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:79) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1] 
   at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0
   at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction$3$1.doRun(TransportUpdateAction.java:227) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.
   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_74-cedar14] 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_74-cedar14] 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_74-cedar14] 
 Caused by: org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutionException: failed to run inline script [if (ctx._source.field.names == null) 
     ctx._source.field.names=newItems 
  else 
     ctx._source.field.names<< newItems; 
     ctx._source.field.names = ctx._source.field.names.flatten().unique()] using lang [groovy] 
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:253) ~[org.elasticsearch.
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:251) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1] 
    ... 8 common frames omitted 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'names' on null object 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60) ~[org.codehaus.groovy.groovy-all-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:172) ~[org.codehaus.groovy.groovy-all-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47) ~[org.codehaus.groovy.groovy-all-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296) ~[org.codehaus.groovy.groovy-all-2.4.0.
    at 889babff0826c95e16279a9fb1fd2eb97a63e642.run(889babff0826c95e16279a9fb1fd2eb97a63e642:1) ~[na:na] 
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:248) ~[org.elasticsearch.
```

Here is a document example:

```
{ 
   "field": {
      "names": ["A","B","C"],
      "A": { "name": "A is awesome" },
      "B": { "name": "B is awesome" },
      "C": { "name": "C is awesome" }
   },
   "email": "x@gmail.com"
}
```

Mappings:

```
"my_index": {
"mappings": {
  "my_type": {
     "properties": {
       "email": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "email"
       },
       "field": {
         "properties": {
           "A": {
             "properties": {
               "name": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "analyzer": "lowercase"
                }
              }
            },
            "B": {
             "properties": {
               "name": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "analyzer": "lowercase"
                }
              }
            },
            "C": {
             "properties": {
               "name": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "analyzer": "lowercase"
                }
              }
            },
            "names": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "lowercase"
             }
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
  override def addTerms(id: String, path: String, terms: Set[String]): Future[Unit] = {
    val groovyScript =
      s"""if (ctx._source.$path == null)
          |   ctx._source.$path=newItems
          |else
          |   ctx._source.$path<< newItems;
          |ctx._source.$path = ctx._source.$path.flatten().unique();""".stripMargin
    client.execute(ElasticDsl.update id id in indexName / documentType retryOnConflict 5 script {
      script(groovyScript).params(Map("newItems" -> terms.toArray))
    }).map(_ => Unit)
  }   

  override def update(id: String, field: NestedFieldValue) = {
    client.execute {
      ElasticDsl.update(id) in indexName / documentType retryOnConflict 5 doc field
    }
  }
```

I looked on the document the script fails on, and tried to manually run this script using curl, and it worked.
So the document is not really the problem.

I am running this update for 38 documents, meaning it will run 38 times.
The exception is thrown on a different document every time I try it this update from the beginning (meaning running it again on those 38 documents)

Not sure what I am missing here. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show one document that fails and the mapping you're using?

Comment: The issue is that however you are running the script, `ctx._source.field` is ending up `null`

Comment: Is `names` a `nested` field?

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments! @Val thanks, added an example to the document and the mappings. tim_yates I understand that ctx._source.field is null, but I don't understand why..because it is not, I queried this document and verfied it, maybe becuase I use source there is a problem loading it into memory? Andrei Stefan Yes.

Comment: Shouldn't  `else 
         ctx._source.field.names<< newItems; 
         ctx._source.field.names = ctx._source.field.names.flatten().unique()` be with curly brakets: `else {
         ctx._source.field.names<< newItems; 
         ctx._source.field.names = ctx._source.field.names.flatten().unique() }`

Comment: I think he's either creating the array (if) or adding to it (else) and then in both cases he will flatten the array. The indentation could be better, though.

Comment: @Tomer are you running this script in parallel somehow?

Comment: Thanks Val, fixed the indentation. @Andrei Stefan hell yea, I am working on 38 documents in paralell. actually sending 76 parllel requests. 2 for every document. so if for example I want to add "D" into this document, I will run the above script to add it to the array. and another request to add a new field to "field" which will add `"D": { "name": "D is awesome" }` to "field". do you think this can be a problem?

Comment: Is your code that runs these scripts thread safe? Meaning this entire code block? `if (ctx._source.field.names == null) 
   ctx._source.field.names=newItems 
else 
   ctx._source.field.names<< newItems; 
ctx._source.field.names = ctx._source.field.names.flatten().unique()`

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think it is. I added it to my question. this code is running in parallel (37 more futures) and it looks thread safe to me. Do you see a problem here?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it seems, that flatning the 2 futures, for every document fix the problem. Meaning, instead of running this 2 updates (one script and one regular update) in parallel, I run them sequentially. Sound like a bug in elasticsearch? having problem to update a document with groovy and regular api in parallel?

Comment: @Tomer Groovy is not my thing... where is the second update in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109514/discussion-between-tomer-and-andrei-stefan).